# how to handle UI actions on front-end responsively while waiting for the processing in back-end?

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, frontend, backend

Use a StackOverflow Q&A thread as an example - when you vote up, vote down, or favorite a question, you can see the UI quickly respond to that action with changes in the # of up-votes on the side.

How can we achieve that effect? If send every of such action to back-end for processing and use the returned response to update UI, you will see a slow update and feel the glitches. But if put some of the logic on the front-end, you will also need to take care of the fraud/abuse etc before reflecting the action on UI, i.e - before changing the # of up-votes, don't you need to make sure that's a valid click by an valid user first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You make sure that a valid user is using the app *before* a user clicks on anything. This is done through authentication, and it must include various protection mechanisms against malicious users.
2. When a user clicks, a call is made to a server. In a properly architected app this call is lightweight, and the server responds very quickly. I don't know why you believe that "you will see a slow update and feel the glitches". Adding an upvote to the database should take a few hundred milliseconds at most (including the roundtrip from the client), especially if the commit is asynchronous or a memcache is used.
3. If a database update results in a need to do some complex operations, typically these operations are not done right away. For example, a cron job may run periodically to compute new rankings, etc., precisely because you do not want every user to wait. Alternatively, a task is created and put in a task queue to be executed when resources are available - again to make sure that a user does not wait.
4. In some apps a UI is updated immediately after the call to the server is made, before any response from a server arrives. You can do it when the consequences of a failed call are negligible. For example, if an upvote fails to be saved in the database, it's not a disaster, especially if it happens once in a million tries. Again, in a properly architected app calls fail extremely rarely.

This is a decision that an app developer needs to make. I would not update a UI before a server response if such an update may lead a user to believe that some other action is now possible. For example, if a user uploads a new photo, I would not show icons to edit or share this photo until I know that the photo is safely saved.

Comment: Great points. For 2 - if back-end need to not only update the database, but do a series of checks (and hence need to pull some additional data from database) and complicated computations, it won't be as trivial as a few milliseconds. For example, compute the ranking score for the question and the reputation score for the users involved, upon receiving the front-end actions

Comment: Got it. So its still a good practice to call back-end for the expected changes (instead of "fake" the change on the front-end using separate logics) but make sure to move the complex operations onto the pipeline to get processed asynchronously.